# Horizontal scrollbar stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I am looking for a solution for a sticky-bottom horizontal scrollbar.
On view, there is a huge table and I didn't want to give fixed height to that so we'll have page level vertical scrollbar but I have given fixed width so there will be a grid-level horizontal scrollbar.

The problem is I don't want to go all the way down below to use the horizontal scrollbar, I am looking for a solution to make the horizontal scrollbar stick to the bottom of the view.

[image]

Comment: provide some code to help you, it's necessary

Comment: check the example @FedericoMigueletto 
https://codepen.io/devashishg/pen/zYKXjYm

I didn't want to scroll the page down to access horizontal scroll 
want that scrollbar sticky to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out a workaround using a custom scroll bar.
checkout here,
https://codepen.io/devashishg/pen/oNzREaw

```js
const $scroller = document.getElementById("scroller");
const $containers = document.getElementById("container_body");
const $wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
let ignoreScrollEvent = false;
animation = null;
const scrollbarPositioner = () => {
  const scrollTop = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  const wrapperTop = $wrapper.offsetTop;
  const wrapperBottom = wrapperTop + $wrapper.offsetHeight;

  const topMatch = window.innerHeight + scrollTop >= wrapperTop;
  const bottomMatch = scrollTop <= wrapperBottom;

  if (topMatch && bottomMatch) {
    const inside =
      wrapperBottom >= scrollTop &&
      window.innerHeight + scrollTop <= wrapperBottom;

    if (inside) {
      $scroller.style.bottom = "0px";
    } else {
      const offset = scrollTop + window.innerHeight - wrapperBottom;

      $scroller.style.bottom = offset + "px";
    }
    $scroller.classList.add("visible");
  } else {
    $scroller.classList.remove("visible");
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(scrollbarPositioner);
};
requestAnimationFrame(scrollbarPositioner);
$scroller.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  if (ignoreScrollEvent) return false;
  if (animation) cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
  animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    ignoreScrollEvent = true;
    $containers.scrollLeft = $scroller.scrollLeft;
    ignoreScrollEvent = false;
  });
});
$containers.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  if (ignoreScrollEvent) return false;
  if (animation) cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
  animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    ignoreScrollEvent = true;
    $scroller.scrollLeft = $containers.scrollLeft;
    ignoreScrollEvent = false;
  });
});
```

```css
.long {
  width: 1550px;
}

#container_body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#scroller {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: none;
}

#scroller.visible {
  display: block;
}

#scroller .long {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
Hello<br/>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container_body">
      <div class="long"> Long text</div>
      Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />Long text
      <br />A. Long text
      <br />
    </div>
    <div id="scroller">
      <div class="long">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
Bye
```

please share any alternate solution if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use these to make a custom scrollbar. You may also position it as you want.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* style it here */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    /* style it here */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    /* style it here */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    /* style it here */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    /* style it here */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    /* style it here */
}
```

Comment: This didn't help. because position and margin kind of properties didn't work.
you can give it a try here https://codepen.io/devashishg/pen/zYKXjYm